# Make table 100% width if parents have width in percent

Tags: html, css, reactjs, width, css-tables

I have issues with 100% width of table, I have div content width in pixels, then all sub divs are in percent and work good, but table doesn't.

```css
   #content{
        position: fixed;
        float: left;
        top: 116px;
        width: calc(100% - 125px);
        height: calc(100% - 124px);
        background-color: #bdc9ce;
    }
    .size-3{
        width: 33.333%;
    }
    .inputs-root{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .input-table{
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div id="content">
       <div class="size-3">
         <div class="inputs-root">
           <tbody class="input-table">
             <tr>....
             </tr>
           </tbody>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So I don't know, why is width of table longer than .inputs-root... any tips ?
I tried to set `table-layout: fixed;` and `word-break` too but still same

**EDIT**

**MY CODE :**

Render of entire list of inputs - http://pastebin.com/jZvzdgyT

Render of single inputs - http://pastebin.com/DEmAdiD2
its writed in reactjs, so just look on render methods

**PICTURES**

still larger than parent's div
[image]

parent's div -
[image]

Comment: can you add the whole code

Comment: I could not find the <table> tag in your code !

Comment: @PraveenMurali I am trying to set it inside browser for now, i am setting tbody element

Answer (score 0):

If you have have following css for your table then remove this

```
table{
    display:block;
}
```

This overrides the default display mode for the table (`display:table`)

Removing this might solve the problem

Comment: In default, tbody have display: table-row-group and i think, i am not able to remove this, so i can only change property, any tips which one? :D

Comment: it would be better if I had full code. can you set up a fiddle with table's code

Comment: you didn't use <table> tags

Comment: wrap your table rows `<tr></tr>` inside `<table></table>`

Comment: even if i put `<tbody>` inside `<table>` ...-> `<table><tbody><tr><tr/></tbody></table>` its result same

Comment: I'm sorry but your code is reactjs so Icant make sense of it. but what are the styles for tbody when you see in developer tools. maybe you can send a screenshot on : http://tinypic.com/

Comment: screens added in question

Comment: your table width is more then div. try inserting this in your table css  `max-width:100%;`

Comment: Still same result

Comment: Sorry, it's all I can gather from this much but here's the last one add this to your table css `max-width:100%;overflow-x:auto;;`

Answer (score 0):

use **`<table>`** tag it's works fine

- => width of div.size-3 is 33% of div#content
- ==> width of div.input-root is 100% of div.size-3 it's 33% of div#content
- ===>width of  div.input-table is 100% of div.input-root it's 33% of div#content.

I'm added the snippet below.

```css
#content{
        position: fixed;
        float: left;
        top: 116px;
        width: calc(100% - 125px);
        height: calc(100% - 124px);
        background-color: #bdc9ce;
    }
    .size-3{
        width: 33.333%;
    }
    .inputs-root{
        width: 100%;
    }
    .input-table{
        width: 100%;
        background-color:red;
    }
```

```html
<div id="content">
       <div class="size-3">
         <div class="inputs-root">
           <table class="input-table">
             <tbody >
               <tr>....
               </tr>
             </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @LukášUnzeitig pictures not works,if you post more code then only we can give the absolute solution .else we can just predict it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found solution, i just need to set width of  inside  to 100%, it looks that width of input blocked min width.